# error on agora package at flutter run ios

Tags: ios, flutter, agora.io

i have to problem with agora.
1: in ios i have error on flutter run:

```
        config.encryptionKdfSalt = Data(bytes: encryptionKdfSalt)
                                   ^
/Users/iman/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-4.2.1/ios/Classes/Base/Extensions.swift:121:22: warning: 'delay' is deprecated
            "delay": delay,
                     ^
/Users/iman/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-4.2.1/ios/Classes/Base/RtcEngine.swift:684:31: warning: 'startAudioMixing(_:loopback:replace:cycle:)' is deprecated: use startAudioMixing(.., startPos) instead
        callback.code(engine?.startAudioMixing(params["filePath"] as! String, loopback: params["loopback"] as! Bool, replace: params["replace"] as! Bool, cycle: (params["cycle"] as! NSNumber).intValue))
                              ^
/Users/iman/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-4.2.1/ios/Classes/Base/RtcEngine.swift:724:31: warning: 'getAudioMixingDuration()' is deprecated: use getAudioFileInfo:filePath instead.
```

---

2: in android voice call, after 5 minutes above, voice not transfer between clients.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the first one, it looks like you're using a deprecated method. Make sure that you're using the latest version of the SDK and passing the correct parameters.
2. Can you please provide some more context for this? What channel profile are you using? Are you using tokens? It would be best if you could share the SDK logs.

You can also, ask your question on the [Agora Developer Slack Community](https://www.agora.io/en/join-slack/)